# File not found error error using #include

Tags: c++, xcode

I’m brand new to C++ and am having a hard time figuring out how to add files to a program’s search path.

The main.cpp file in the C++ library calls many files, such as QApplication, QObject, QEventLoop, etc., via

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QEventLoop> etc.
```

Running main.cpp leads to “file not found” errors for most of these. I know where this multitude of files is located on my machine. For example, QApplication is in
usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.15.2/lib/QTwidgets.framework.

Is there a way to fix this error this other than copying all files into the library containing main.cpp? Is there a standard search path I should use? Can the problem be fixed at the terminal?

I’m using Xcode 12.4 on Mac OS 10.15.4.

Comment: Why are you writing a `.cpp` file if I may to ask? as you said, you want to use the library from your python script. Is it `.dll` that you have?

Comment: For now, I just want to be able to run the .cpp file . Later I'll be using the library from my python script, which, in turn, will be converted to a Mac application bundle as part of a bigger project.

Comment: Can you post your project file? [.pro]

Comment: For what it's worth, Qt programming is easier if you use Qt Creator as your IDE. You'll have to configure Xcode to understand the search path. I haven't used Xcode for C++, so  I'm not sure how to add that path or the QtWidgets as a framework.

Comment: Many IDE should let you have a starting project where the code is already organised in an appropriate way. You simply follow the pattern (add files at the same location) and path should already be ajusted. Also many tool existing to add packages and would usually setup everything properly. Sometime it is simply better to works the way it is intended. I have seens some custom structures that have 0 benefit over the default setup and only extra problems (like hard to compile elsewhere).